# partition and write dataframe by two functions of a column with output mapping to specified directory structure

Tags: pyspark

If I have a dataframe with a field `tm` that is of type `timestamp`, lets say it spans several days, lots of data. Can I partition by time and get things written into folders like this:

```
gs://project/data/date=2019-09-19/hour=00/_SUCCESS
gs://project/data/date=2019-09-19/hour=00/part_000-....parquet
...
gs://project/data/date=2019-09-19/hour=01/_SUCCESS
...
gs://project/data/date=2019-09-20/hour=00/_SUCCESS
```

Say there are 36 hours all together, I'm trying to get 36 folders, and maybe 360 output partitions across them.

I see that I can do something like

```
df.repartition(360, F.date_format('tm', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), F.hour('tm'))
```

and there is also

```
df.write.partitionBy( ...
```

but I'm not sure if I can have pyspark write to all 36 folders in parallel. Maybe I have to write to each folder one by one, just filter out the hour I want and write to it -- but then I'll under-utilize my cluster since each hour only has 10 output partitions.

I think it is easier if I have columns `date` and `hour` in the dataframe, but I didn't want to do that, I just wanted the one `tm` column.